# doInBackground not working in fragment (Error Fatal exception : AsyncTask #1)

Tags: android

Here is my Fragment

```
public class LeftFragment extends Fragment{
ListView listView;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<School> schoollist = null;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.left_fragment, container, false);
    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    return v;
}
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        schoollist = new ArrayList<School>();
        try{
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("School");
            query.orderByAscending("index");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject name : ob){
                School map = new School();
                map.setCount((String)name.get("count"));
                map.setName((String)name.get("name"));
                schoollist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        listView = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.lv_left);
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(getActivity(), schoollist);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
}
```

}

This is the Error i am getting (Fatal exception : AsyncTask #1)

```
        05-10 23:48:25.232  20039-20731/animuco.com.ckemi E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: animuco.com.ckemi, PID: 20039
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.LeftFragment$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(LeftFragment.java:66)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.LeftFragment$RemoteDataTask.doInBackground(LeftFragment.java:41)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-10 23:48:25.602  20039-20039/animuco.com.ckemi E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity animuco.com.ckemi.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{44814858 V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,486} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:350)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:294)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.LeftFragment$RemoteDataTask.onPreExecute(LeftFragment.java:54)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at animuco.com.ckemi.Fragment.LeftFragment.onCreateView(LeftFragment.java:38)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:953)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1136)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1499)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:488)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2298)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16645)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5622)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String` not by the Fragment

This part made the error

```
map.setCount((String)name.get("count"));
map.setName((String)name.get("name"));
```

and Rewrite the part like this

```
map.setCount(String.valueOf(name.get("count")));
map.setName(String.valueOf(name.get("name")));
```